# Why does count(*) not return a single-group?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, aggregate-functions

My table and queries are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
 num NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1;

CREATE TABLE test2 (
 num NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test2;

SELECT count(*)/"c2" FROM test1, (SELECT count(*) "c2" FROM test2);

DROP TABLE test1;
DROP TABLE test2;
```

Why do queries 1 and 2 return a single value (5) but the division (query 3) returns a ORA-00937 error?

If I understand correctly count(*) is a aggregate function and should return a single value.

Comment: Try `SELECT count(*)/MAX("c2")`

Comment: It works, but that doesn't solve the mystery :)

Comment: There is no mystery here. In this context `count()` is used as an aggregate function, and it's not allowed to mix an aggregate function and individual column or expression in the select list unless you pass in that individual column or expression as a parameter to another aggregate function or include it in the `group by` clause.

Comment: It does return a single group. But then you're using a pre-ANSI style `,` join with no other conditions (so, therefore, a `CROSS JOIN`), so that the value is joined to *each* row of `test1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to use the column `c2` without an aggregate function in a aggregation query.

You can use:

```
SELECT count(*)/MAX("c2")
```

or:

```
SELECT count(*)/MIN("c2")
```

Other ways would be:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM test1) 
       / (SELECT count(*) FROM test2)
FROM dual ;
```

or:

```
SELECT "c1" / "c2" 
FROM (SELECT count(*) "c1" FROM test1)
   , (SELECT count(*) "c2" FROM test2) ;
```

or better using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT "c1" / "c2" 
FROM  (SELECT count(*) "c1" FROM test1) x1
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT count(*) "c2" FROM test2) x2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT count(*)/c2
FROM test1 cross join
     (SELECT count(*) as c2
      FROM test2
     );
```

This is an aggregation query, that returns one row.  There is no `group by` clause in the outer query.  This means that *all* column references in the outer query need to be in aggregation functions.

The column reference `c2` is not in an aggregation function.  Hence, it generates the appropriate error.  The error text explains this:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function : SELECT count(*)/"c2" FROM test1, (SELECT count(*) "c2" FROM test2)

That is, `c2` is not a "single-group" group function.

In other words, having the aggregation in a subquery doesn't count.